# Are Hadoop Sequence Files Supported by Filesystems other than HDFS

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, hdfs, sequencefile

Is the sequence file format supported by any other file system apart from HDFS? I am specifically interested in whether the sequence file format can be used for merging and storing the small files on filesystems like e.g. HFS+ or NTFS.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequence files are not limited to HDFS in any way. You can use Sequence Files with any general purpose file system including NTFS and HFS+.

They are in no way special in this regard when compared to other binary files.

Comment: Thanks. I had this doubt because all the material that I found on Google, everywhere it was being used for hadoop. Thanks for the clarification. Also it would be great if you happen to know any good sample application/code of sequenceFile being used for other file system?